# Сравнение элементов коллекции с помощью Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Есть коллекция A с 3 свойствами A.A (DateTime), A.B (integer), A.C (bool), и она состоит из пар записей, например 26/12/2018, 1, true - 27/12/2018, 1, false, т.е вторая запись как бы закрывает первую по полю A.B и при A.C - false, но таких записей может быть несколько, и мне нужно получить количество не закрытых записей

Comment: Найти минимум в коллекции В и пробежаться 1 раз по коллекции А?

Comment: Мы меня еще больше запутали, приведите примеры данных на входе и выходе

Comment: Почему Any не подходит, оно же до первого соответствия проверяет?

Comment: Мне кажется тут было бы лучше увидеть входные данные и что нужно из них в итоге получить. А то так действительно не очень понятно...

Comment: изменил на реальное задание

Comment: Не понял логику закрывания и откуда 13 месяц?

Comment: @tym 12, ошибся, true - открывает, false - закрывает, A.B как id, но не уникальный т.е может быть много открытых с одинаковым A.B и закрытых тоже много, но закрытое всегда позднее по времени за открытое

Answer (score 1):

Ох, ну и умеете же вы задавать вопросы...
Если я правильно понял, то:

Допустим у нас такой вид нашего объекта:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int id, DateTime date, bool isOpen)
    {
        Id = id;
        Date = date;
        IsOpen = isOpen;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
}
```

Далее сформируем тестовую коллекцию:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1, new DateTime(2018,12,26), true),
    new Item(1, new DateTime(2018,12,27), false),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,23), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,24), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,25), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,26), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,1), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,2), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,3), false),
};
```

Ну и далее по порядку:

- Как я понял, int (в моем случае это свойство Id), это некий номер некой задачи (или чего то в этом духе), значит все одинаковые номера мы по сути должны считать за одну "задачу". Тогда логично будет сделать группировку по ним:

  ```
  var result = Items.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
  ```
- Далее для удобства создадим анонимный тип с названием группы и отсортированными по дате значениям (чисто для нашего удобства):

  ```
  var result = Items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
      .Select(group => new { Id = group.Key, Items = group.OrderBy(x => x.Date) });
  ```
- Теперь наша цель отловить все задачи, которые открыты (то есть не имеют `IsOpen == false`). Сделать это мы можем путем `.All()` и `Where()` (или `.Count()` если надо сразу посчитать):

  ```
  var result = Items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
      .Select(group => new { Id = group.Key, Items = group.OrderBy(x => x.Date) })
      .Where(x => x.Items.All(a => a.IsOpen));
  ```

На этом этапе мы получим примерно следующие данные:

[image: Result]

Видим, что у нас один анонимный объект, который имеет `Id=2` и в `Items` собранные все объекты с данным Id. Осталось посчитать то, что нам нужно, но это думаю вы сделаете уже сами...

Answer (score 1):

Я нагло скоммуниздил код из соседнего ответа (только добавил тестовый пример)

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int id, DateTime date, bool isOpen)
    {
        Id = id;
        Date = date;
        IsOpen = isOpen;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
}

List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1, new DateTime(2018,12,26), true),
    new Item(1, new DateTime(2018,12,27), false),
    new Item(1, new DateTime(2018,12,28), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,23), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,24), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,25), true),
    new Item(2, new DateTime(2018,11,26), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,1), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,2), true),
    new Item(3, new DateTime(2018,10,3), false),
};
```

Мне кажется, нам надо после группировки, каждую группу отсортировать по убыванию, и все элементы, что будут в начале отсортированного результата открытыми, по умолчанию не закрывались (так как не будет такого закрывающего элемента, у которого дата больше).

```
var result = Items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(group => 
                   new { Id = group.Key, 
                         Items = group
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                                  .TakeWhile(x=>x.IsOpen).ToArray() })
            .Where(x => x.Items.Any());
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]